# Split CSV cell, concatenate a value then recombine?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I want to take the CSV contents of a cell and prepend a value to each value. For example:

BEFORE: A,B,C,D
PREPEND: z
AFTER: zA,zB,zC,zD

I currently have this

```
=JOIN(",",SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""),","))
```

But can't work out how or where to do the concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

```
=JOIN(",","z"&SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""),","))
```

Comment: Please include some explanation with your code.

Comment: @jonsca I really believe this is sufficient. The question is where to add "z" in OP's code? I showed where to add "z".  Would it make a difference if I added "You add it right before the SPLIT"?  Will the viewers get anything extra outta that extra sentence? Or Would it have been better to just leave it as a comment?

Comment: So the story with these, and it's not just an issue with you, is that they end up in the low quality queue due to having no supporting text, which inevitably creates more work for someone else.  So yes, even a snippet of explanation is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for that |'_'|. Unfortunately it only seems to work on the first match so the output is just zA. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Chris Use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER or Wrap the whole formula in ARRAYFORMULA()